# Why this query does not trigger partition pruning in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning, pruning

I just noticed Postgres (checked on version 13 and 14) behavior that surprised me. I have a simple table `volume` with `id` and unique text column `name`. Second table `dir` has 3 columns: `id`, `volume_id` and `path`. This table is partitioned by hash on `volume_id` column. Here is full table schema with sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dir (
   id BIGSERIAL,
   volume_id BIGINT,
   path TEXT
) PARTITION BY HASH (volume_id);

CREATE TABLE dir_0
    PARTITION OF dir FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 3, remainder 0);
CREATE TABLE dir_1
    PARTITION OF dir FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 3, remainder 1);
CREATE TABLE dir_2
    PARTITION OF dir FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 3, remainder 2);


CREATE TABLE volume(
    id BIGINT,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO volume (id, name) VALUES (1, 'vol1'), (2, 'vol2'), (3, 'vol3');
INSERT INTO dir (volume_id, path) SELECT i % 3 + 1, 'path_' || i FROM generate_series(1,1000) AS i;
```

Now, given the volume name, I need to find all the rows from the `dir` table on that volume. I can do that in 2 different ways.
**Query #1**

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM dir AS d
    INNER JOIN volume AS v ON d.volume_id = v.id
    WHERE v.name = 'vol1';
```

Which produces query plan:

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Hash Join (cost=1.05..31.38 rows=333 width=37) (actual time=0.186..0.302 rows=333 loops=1) |
| Hash Cond: (d.volume_id = v.id) |
| -> Append (cost=0.00..24.00 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.154 rows=1000 loops=1) |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_0 d_1 (cost=0.00..6.34 rows=334 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.032 rows=334 loops=1) |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_1 d_2 (cost=0.00..6.33 rows=333 width=24) (actual time=0.006..0.029 rows=333 loops=1) |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_2 d_3 (cost=0.00..6.33 rows=333 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.026 rows=333 loops=1) |
| -> Hash (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 9kB |
| -> Seq Scan on volume v (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Filter: (name = 'vol1'::text) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 2 |
|  |
| Planning Time: 0.500 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.364 ms |

As you can see this query leads to a sequential scan on all 3 partitions of the `dir` table.

---

Alternatively, we can write this query like this:

**Query #2**

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * FROM dir AS d
    WHERE volume_id = (SELECT id FROM volume AS v WHERE v.name = 'vol1');
```

In that case we get following query plan:

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Append (cost=1.04..27.54 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=0.010..0.066 rows=333 loops=1) |
| InitPlan 1 (returns $0) |
| -> Seq Scan on volume v (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=1) |
| Filter: (name = 'vol1'::text) |
| Rows Removed by Filter: 2 |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_0 d_1 (cost=0.00..7.17 rows=334 width=24) (never executed) |
| Filter: (volume_id = $0) |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_1 d_2 (cost=0.00..7.16 rows=333 width=24) (never executed) |
| Filter: (volume_id = $0) |
| -> Seq Scan on dir_2 d_3 (cost=0.00..7.16 rows=333 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.037 rows=333 loops=1) |
| Filter: (volume_id = $0) |
| Planning Time: 0.063 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.093 ms |

Here we can see that partitions `dir_0` and `dir_1` have `never executed` annotation.

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/swihQpFqUHhBujfoLK9JNe/4)

**My question is:**
Why in the first case is there no partition pruning? Postgres already knows that the `volume.name` column is unique and that it will translate into a single `volume_id`. I would like to get a good intuition on when partition pruning can happen during query execution.

Answer (score 0):

To get partition pruning with a hash join, you'd need to add a condition on `d.volume_id` to your query. No inference is made from the join with `volume`.

Your second query shows partition pruning; the "never executed" means that the query executor pruned the scan of certain partitions.

An alternative method that forces a nested loop join and prunes partitions should be

```
SELECT *
FROM volume AS v
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM dir
                       WHERE dir.volume_id = v.id
                       OFFSET 0) AS d
WHERE v.name = 'vol1';
```

`OFFSET 0` prevents anything except a nested loop join. Different from your query, that should also work if `volumn.name` is not unique.

Comment: I guess that the main takeaway is that there must be a condition on the partition column. Unfortunately, your proposition with lateral join doesn't work (at least for that example) and produces hash join with scan on all partitions.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans for making such queries use partition pruning?

Comment: Ah. Reading your question again, I see that your second query already does get partition pruning, so you should be good. I am surprised that my query doesn't do the same thing; could you show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for my query?

Comment: Here you go: https://explain.depesz.com/s/PsIi

Comment: Here is a link to DB Fiddle if you want to play with it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/swihQpFqUHhBujfoLK9JNe/4

Comment: Thanks. An `OFFSET 0` did the trick.